# A and B are 3x3 matrices. Show that $AB \neq 0$ if both matrices have a rank of 2.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

A and B are $3\times 3$ matrices. I want to show that $AB \neq 0$ if both matrices have rank 2.

Comment: Well $AB=0$ if $\mathrm{Ker}(A) \subseteq \mathrm{Ran}(B)$, hence....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use [Sylvester's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties)
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Rank}(AB) \geq \operatorname{Rank}(A)+\operatorname{Rank}(B)-3
\end{align}

Comment: great, that will work. thanks!